# Displaying console output creates EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So i am in the process of making an app and one of the features is where you ping an API connected to a database and display one of the returned pieces of information. In this case it is the summary information on certain car models that have already been loaded into the database. The code where the error happens is

`import UIKit class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var trim : Trims?
    var trims: ReturnedDataObject?
    @IBOutlet weak var summaryLabel: UILabel!`

```
@IBAction func showSummary(sender: AnyObject) {
    summaryLabel.text = trims?.summary

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The information shows in the console output and the exact error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code1, address:0x0). When i clicked the button linked to the above text to show the summary text is when i get the error. I can provide more information if needed. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is not the actual error, try to post the actual error message that crashes your code and look for the line where it happens.

Comment: Managed to grab this http://i.imgur.com/FER1VMN.png

Comment: is summary label hooked up as iboutlet in the interface builder? try letting xcode continue running the app after EXC_BAD_ACCESS and post the resulting error message - EXC_BAD_ACCESS only tells you THAT something went wrong, not WHAT.

Comment: Yep im 100% sure the summary label is hooked up as an IBoutlet. Also once the error pops you cannot do anything else in the app.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `summaryLabel.text = trims?.summary` line and check summaryLabel. I am pretty sure it's nil.

Comment: Yep i put the breakpoint in right at line of code that you mentioned and the error did not appear. What does this mean in terms of changing my code to correctly get the summary is display?

Answer (score 0):

//dont have rep for comment.

So 2 things, summaryLabel.text = trims?.summary

First of all check if you don't have some old connections on that Label that u might need to delete.

Second - if the label connection is 100% good, then this trims looks nil to me

```
var trims: ReturnedDataObject?
...
summaryLabel.text = trims?.summary
```

If u never initialize trims in the DetailViewController class (dunno if this is whole code), then you prolly cannot get the summary on a trims that is nil. 
Check with some println  if trims is nil
If it is then you need to put something into trims before you call the trims?.summary. Also i think you should make it:

```
trims!.summary
```

, cause i dont see why would u need optional there if you want to use the value.

```
@IBAction func showSummary(sender: AnyObject) {
   if trims != nil {
       summaryLabel.text = trims!.summary
   } else {
       println("trims is nil")
   }
}
```

You can replace trims with trim as in your screenshot.

Also another question, are you sure summary is String ?